# Set Theory Question: "Introduction to Calculus and Classical Analysis" 4th ed., ex. 1.1.4.

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Assume x={a}.

**(a)** $\bigcup${x} = x for all x.

**1.** Doesn't this mean {{a}}$\bigcup${{a}}$\bigcup${{a}} . . . $\bigcup${{a}} which would equal {a}?

**(b)** {$\bigcup$x} = x iff x is a singleton.

**2.** Wouldn't that expand to {{a}$\bigcup${a}$\bigcup${a} . . . $\bigcup${a}} which would end up being {{a}} which is not equal to {a}=x?

**3.** How and why is **(b)** true?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I think you replaced the answer in 1. and 2., in 1 it should be {{a}} and in 2. it should be {a}.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the correct definitions. In this case it's

> Let $X$ be a set (containing sets), then
>   $$\bigcup X := \{ y : \exists Y\in X: y\in Y\}$$

From this we can prove the given statements. Let $x$ be a set. Then

$$\bigcup \{x\} = \{ y :\exists Y\in\{x\}:y\in Y\}$$

There is only one $Y$ in $\{x\}$, namely $Y=x$. We see $x$ as a set, therefore

$$\bigcup \{x\} = \{ y : y\in x\} = x$$

For (b):

> Assume $\{\bigcup x\}=x$. Now $\bigcup x$ is just a set, say $a=\bigcup x$, so $\{a\} = x$, but then $x$ is already a singleton. 
>
>  Now assume $x$ is a singleton, i.e. $\{a\}=x$. But we know from (a) that, if we interpret $a$ as a set (instead of $x$), we can write $a=\bigcup\{a\}=\bigcup x$, so $\{\bigcup x\}=x$.

Comment: Does not make sense to me. I'm sorry. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either --- specifically the second equality in the last display. $\bigcup\{x\}$ should be $x$, not $\{x\}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, does **(b)** make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, statement (b) in the question is correct. If $x$ is a singleton, say $x=\{y\}$, then $\bigcup x=\bigcup\{y\}=y$ and so $\{\bigcup x\}=\{y\}=x$.   The converse, "if $\{\bigcup x\}=x$ then $x$ is a singleton," is trivial because $\{\bigcup x\}$ is a singleton.  (I'm assuming throughout that all this is in the context of a set theory like ZF, where everything is a set.)

Comment: @dek As Andreas indicated, I made a mistake. Corrected it and added proof for (b). If there is still something confusing, please write what exactly confuses you.

Comment: @SK19 Thank you for your patience. I made a massive, incorrect assumption about the operator when it lacks an explicit index, and the notion that literally everything is a set. I found a copy of Enderton's _Elements of Set Theory_ and thereafter it became obvious. Again, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that $x = \{a \}$ is irrelevant and actually harmful here. For any set $x$ we have that $\bigcup \{ x \} = x$.

Why? $\bigcup \{x \} = \{ z \mid \exists y \in \{x \} \colon z \in y \} = \{ z \mid z \in x \} = x$ (the last equality follows by extensionality).

Now, if $x$ is a singleton, i.e. $x = \{a \}$, then, by what we've shown above, $\{ \bigcup x \} = \{ \bigcup \{a \} \}= \{a \} = x$.

I'll leave it to you to show the converse. (If $x$ contains two distinct elements, then $\{ \bigcup x \} \neq x$.

Comment: Thank you.

That does not make sense to me. If x={a} then {{a}}={x} which is not equal to {a}. I must be misunderstanding the notation. Sorry.

Comment: @dek We are taking about $\{ \bigcup \{a \} \}$, not about $\{ \{ a \} \}$

Comment: Wouldn't that expand to {{a}⋃{a}⋃{a} . . . ⋃{a}} which would end up being {{a}} which is not equal to {a}=x?

Comment: @dek No, it wouldn't. I suggest you revisit the formal definition of the union operator.

Comment: Thank you. Any reference(s)?

Comment: @dek It's surely covered wherever you got this exercise from. But since you asked: For a given set $x$ we define $\bigcup x := \{z \mid \exists y \in x \colon z \in y\}$ -- it's the set of all sets that are members of some element of $x$.

Comment: About @StefanMesken's suggestion that you revisit the definition of $\bigcup$: More generally, when solving problems involving a mathematical concept, you should first make sure you understand the definition of that concept. If, instead of using the definition, you use your intuition of what the concept "ought" to mean, you will often be misled.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you both for your replies and advice.